# How to set stick=true in full calendar when implementing repeating event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I am currently doing some repeating event of fullCalendar in my code. However when switching to next/prev month, my event getting bug or disappear. I know that `stick` is needed but where should I put it when my code is like this?

```
var repeatingEvents = [{
                        title: sub[x],
                        start: tmefrm[x], 
                        end: tmeto[x], 
                        dow: [har[x]], 
                        ranges: [{
                                start: moment(dtefrm[x]), 
                                end: moment(dteto[x]),
                              }],
                        color: 'green',
                        }];
                        var getEvents = function( start, end ){
                            return repeatingEvents;
                        }
                        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
                            defaultDate: moment(),
                            header: {
                                left: 'prev,next today',
                                center: 'title',
                                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay',
                            },
                            defaultView: 'month',
                            eventRender: function(event, element, view){
                                //console.log(event.start.format());
                                return (event.ranges.filter(function(range){
                                    return (event.start.isBefore(range.end) &&
                                            event.end.isAfter(range.start));
                                }).length)>0;
                            },
                            events: function( start, end, timezone, callback ){
                                var events = getEvents(start,end); //this should be a JSON request
                                callback(events);
                            },
                        });
```

I read the docs which it says that `event must be an Event Object with a title and start at the very least.`

Unless my code is like this it will be easy.

```
var myCalendar = $('#calendar');
myCalendar.fullCalendar();
var myEvent = {
                title: sub[x],
                color: 'green',
                start: tmefrm[x],
                end: tmeto[x],
                dow: [har[x]],
                ranges: [{
                          start: new Date(dtefrm[x]),
                          end: new Date(dteto[x]),
                        }],
                }
                myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', myEvent, [ stick= true]);
```

What I do ?  Is I want to use repeating event, and so far this code make me go far from previous progress but I'm not sure where to put this `stick`.

Any help would be great :)

Answer (score 2):

It's simple!

```
myCalendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent', myEvent, true);
```